# how to move a block or column of text

Tags: vim

I have the following text as a simple case:

```
...
abc xxx 123 456
wer xxx 345 678676
...
```

what I need to move a block of text xxx to another location:

```
...
abc 123 xxx 456
wer 345 xxx 678676
...
```

I think I use visual mode to block a column of text, what are the other commands to move the block to another location?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should use blockwise visual mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).
Then <kbd>d</kbd> to delete block, <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>P</kbd> to paste block.

Answer (score 28):

Try the [link](http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html).

---

Marking text (visual mode)

- <kbd>v</kbd> - start visual mode, mark lines, then do command (such as y-yank)
- <kbd>V</kbd> - start Linewise visual mode
- <kbd>o</kbd> - move to other end of marked area
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> - start visual block mode
- <kbd>O</kbd> - move to Other corner of block
- <kbd>aw</kbd> - mark a word
- <kbd>ab</kbd> - a () block (with braces)
- <kbd>aB</kbd> - a {} block (with brackets)
- <kbd>ib</kbd> - inner () block
- <kbd>iB</kbd> - inner {} block
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - exit visual mode

Visual commands

- <kbd>></kbd> - shift right
- <kbd><</kbd> - shift left
- <kbd>y</kbd> - yank (copy) marked text
- <kbd>d</kbd> - delete marked text
- <kbd>~</kbd> - switch case

Cut and Paste

- <kbd>yy</kbd> - yank (copy) a line
- <kbd>2yy</kbd> - yank 2 lines
- <kbd>yw</kbd> - yank word
- <kbd>y$</kbd> - yank to end of line
- <kbd>p</kbd> - put (paste) the clipboard after cursor
- <kbd>P</kbd> - put (paste) before cursor
- <kbd>dd</kbd> - delete (cut) a line
- <kbd>dw</kbd> - delete (cut) the current word
- <kbd>x</kbd> - delete (cut) current character

Answer (score 14):

One of the few useful command I learned at the beginning of learning VIM is
:1,3 mo 5
This means move text line 1 through 3 to line 5.

Comment: And you can select the lines in visual mode, then press `:` to get `:'<,'>` (equivalent to the `:1,3` part in your answer), and add `mo N`. If you want to move a single line, just `:mo N`. If you are really lazy, you can omit the space (e.g. `:mo5`). Use marks with `mo '{a-zA-Z}`.

Comment: Was searching for this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

1. In VIM, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to go in Visual Block mode
2. Select the required columns with your <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> and press <kbd>x</kbd> to cut them in the buffer.
3. Move cursor to row 1 column 9 and press <kbd>P</kbd> (thats capital P) in command mode.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to get in and out of it.
   ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=729349))

Answer (score 0):

Using an external command "awk".

```
%!awk '{print $1,$3,$2,$4}' test.txt
```

With pure vim

```
:%s,\v(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+),\1 \3 \2 \4,g
```

Another vim solution using global command

```
:g/./normal wdwwP
```